# How to link to multiple targets by tag and not target name?

Tags: cmake

I have a project which defines a bunch of object libraries. The list of object libraries is subject to change very often. The project also defines some static and dynamic libraries which are supposed to include the object libraries.

I want the static/dynamic libraries to automatically link to all object libraries with a certain "tag" and without explicitly mentioning each one in `target_link_libraries()`.

My first thought would be a global variable to which each object lib appends its target name, but I am afraid that this is error-prone and relies on the definition/use order. Is there a better way to "tag" certain targets and then make another target depend upon the tagged targets?

Answer (score 2):

As a "tag" you could use an INTERFACE library and link it with every library you want to tag. With that setup everyone who link with that library will be linked automatically with every "tagged" library.

```
# Create "tag" as a library.
add_library(tag1 INTERFACE)

# libraries_add_tag(tag_name [library ...])
#
# "Tags" given libraries with given tag.
function(libraries_add_tag tag_name)
target_link_libraries(${tag_name} INTERFACE ${ARGN})
endfunction()

# Create some libraries
#
add_library(lib1 ...)
add_library(lib2 ...)

# Add "tag" to those libraries
libraries_add_tag(tag1 lib1 lib2)

# Create final executable
add_executable(exe1 ...)

# Link executable with all tagged libraries
target_link_libraries(exe1 PRIVATE tag1)
```

Comment: Are object libraries properly picked up when "hidden" behind an interface library?

Comment: CMake developers tend to treat OBJECT libraries as "first-class citizens", so they should work in scenarios where "normal" libraries do.

Comment: this solution does not work. OBJECT libraries behind a INTERFACE are not picked up by targets linking to the INTERFACE library. See https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18735